# How can I hide the Homegroup icon on the desktop?

Tags: windows-7, icons, homegroup

Last night a Windows update on my Windows 7 machine added a new "Homegroup" icon to my desktop.

I don't want the icon on my desktop but can't see any way to get rid of it.

It's not listed in the desktop icons under personalisation settings and it's not a regular shortcut so can't be deleted in the usual manner. The context (right click) menu also provides no suitable option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify some registry keys. [Here are the instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/ce6cfcc0-75f6-42a9-bbd6-e12c9b6fa44a) on Microsoft's Windows 7 forums:

> To remove the Home desktop Group icon, you need to manually modify some registry key:

1. Open notepad and then copy the following text (without ===) into it.

   ```
   ================================
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
   "{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu]
   "{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
   "{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu]
   "{B4FB3F98-C1EA-428d-A78A-D1F5659CBA93}"=dword:00000001
   ===========================================
   ```
2. Save the txt file and rename to xxx.reg. Then double click xxx.reg to import the registry key.

   (answer by [Thomas_77](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/thomas_77/?ws=usercard-mini))

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to "Folder Options"
2. Click "View"
3. Scroll down to "Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)", it must be checked
4. Uncheck the checkbox
5. Click "Apply" (the icon will be removed from your desktop)
6. Recheck the checkbox (the icon will not be back)

Comment: Perfect, this works on Windows 8 too. I have no idea why the Homegroup icon suddenly appeared. Maybe it was because I updated my network drivers.

Comment: Much better and easier than the accepted, link-only answer.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8 Enterprise. (However, the icon keeps reappearing occasionally, about once a month. I also don't know why the Homegroup icon suddenly appears.)

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you don't fancy modifying your registry, just stop and disable the follwing services:

`HomeGroup Listener`
`HomeGroup Provider`

Ben

Comment: For those who don't use HomeGroup at all, this is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/ce6cfcc0-75f6-42a9-bbd6-e12c9b6fa44a) provided by Alex, I found an easy way to get rid of Homegroup icon from desktop.

Quote from zzark's answer:

> right-click on the Homegroup icon, select homegroup settings, then
>   select leave homegroup.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the poster meant, because he didn't say he wants to leave the homegroup - he might be using it, he just wants to remove it's icon from the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had to revisit this as that icon reappeared on my desktop, and the answer in the form wasn't working. I was getting lots of import errors. so did a little more searching, and Found another answer as to how to get rid of the icon, that doesn't make you copy paste and import. nor does it have you leave the home group or disable related services

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/unable-to-remove-homegroup-icon/699c4550-c88e-4e0c-b30c-339ca25e52f8

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the desktop and clicking refresh. Simples

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please edit your answer so that it fully explains why it solves the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: This worked for me (Windows 8) even though it's not a permanent solution. (I expect the icon will still randomly reappear someday.) If you have issues with the Homegroup icon randomly reappearing (and fully disabling the Homegroup features is not an option you want to take), this may be worth a shot.